# Finding file type in PHP

Tags: php

Is there any way to find the exact file type in php **without looking for the letters after the dot(.)** ?. Because in that case even if you rename a exe file as png, it will be considered as a png only which is malicious. And some PHP functions like `pathinfo()` also returns the value after dot only which is not reliable. Any suggestion or idea on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: pathinfo() is reliable enough

Comment: Finding the file extension is __not__ the same as finding the file type... doing the latter depends on knowing what the content of each file type is, and reading the file to ascertain it has that content

Comment: @wormhit: That function will returns the value after last dot(.) only. If there is no dot in the file name, it will not have extension in its array.

Comment: @MarkBaker: Is there any way to find the file type?

Comment: beware that finfo_file is has [requirements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.requirements.php) before php 5.3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is not "the extension", it's *the type of the file*. This has been standardized as the [MIME type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type). There are many ways to detect the MIME type of a file, all [previously discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=detect%20mime%20type%20%5Bphp%5D). The preferred method to date is [finfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way to implement this in lower version of PHP?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not the file extension but the mime-type. File extension is nothing more than a naming convention and, as you pointed out, is easy to spoof. You can use the [`finfo_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) function  to get this information.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I check, you can get the exact file type of images with php function. Not sure for arbitrary file.

It is **NOT** possible to detect the file type of any file with 100% accuracy. Ever. You can craft arbitrary file and the file will fail to open as the detected type.

It is possible to detect the file type of binary files to a high level of accuracy, by checking the file signature (the first few bytes). The result is not 100% guaranteed, as said above. You must have a library of file type signature to look up, though.

It is possible, but hard, to detect the file type of text files. Can you differentiate between different languages? And what if the code can compile in more than 1 language?

Answer (score -2):

It is reliable. The extension is exactly the letters after the last dot. If you rename file.exe to file.png, its new extension will be .png and will no longer be executable (in Windows that is, in POSIX systems executability is not controller via file extension).

Comment: The question is about the type of data inside the file. The extension can be modified, and does not reflect the true content of the file.

Comment: No, the question explicitly refers to `file extension`. If the question itself is stated incorrectly, I don't see how my answer should deserve downvoting.

Comment: So you're telling me that if somebody posts an incompetent question, I answer it in good faith, and then they accept something relatively unrelated, I should go back and delete my answer? I answered the question, I did not answer the accepted answer.

Comment: I admit the question is ambiguous, if you haven't gotten the problem yourself. From the question, I (and probably other people who answer the question) guess the intent is to detect the real file type, rather than via file extension, which is not reliable. I told you to read the accepted answer to see the problem that the answer is trying to solve, and reflect back to the question.